# how to normalize 1 dimensional FFT output

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

I'm using FFTW to analyze elevation data, but I started out just by looking at a simple 1D fft to make sure I had everything working.  It seems to work except for the normalization (scale) factors, which I can't figure out from the documentation, mostly because my numbers are ridiculously large.  For example, when I tried to just take an fft of a cosine wave

```
1 6.12323e-017 -1 -1.83697e-016 1 3.06162e-016 -1 -4.28626e-016 1 5.51091e-016 -1      -2.44991e-015 etc...
```

I got the transform to be

```
4.33743e-013 1.06036e+267 3.25205e+265 1.05963e+267 6.49675e+265 1.05743e+267 9.72679e+265 1.05379e+267 1.29349e+266    1.04869e+267 1.61138e+266 1.04216e+267 etc...
```

eg, ridiculously huge numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a pretty clear symptom of reading uninitialized data. You might want to make sure your input vector is actually correct.

Comment: Mystical and Danial got it exactly right.  The problem wasn't the program, it was the dumbass using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are FFT-ing complex numbers, but you initialized your array as normal (without imaginary part) array.

I went ahead onto their side, and found out that there are NEW functions that provide double to complex and complex to double fft-ing.  Neat-o!

Here: http://www.fftw.org/doc/New_002darray-Execute-Functions.html

Comment: *facepalm.  That was it exactly.  The last FFT module I used assumed real numbers unless you specified otherwise.  FFTW assumes complex unless otherwise specified.

Comment: I was lucky, since my friend was doing windowing functions in assembly to speed up my project, and the question was: why is the output data (from the windowing functions) double in size (every other number is zero)...